# Aggregate for unique levels of multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, transpose

Dataset looks like this:

```
 ID  | DELAY |    PERIOD  | TYPE  

 A       5       30 days      1          
 A       1       60 days      1             
 A       2       30 days      2         
 A       1       30 days      2         
 B       2       30 days      2         
 C       10      30 days      2
```

Output should look like:

```
 ID  | AV.DELAY_PERIOD_30DAYS_TYPE_1  |  AV.DELAY_PERIOD_30DAYS_TYPE_2  ...
  A                5                               1.5
```

So, essentially, I need to build a function that builds new variables - average delay, unique per ID, split by each unique period and type.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` to do the summarisation as well as reshaping

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ID~paste0("AV.DELAY_PERIOD_",PERIOD) + TYPE, value.var = "DELAY", mean)
#   ID AV.DELAY_PERIOD_30 days_1 AV.DELAY_PERIOD_30 days_2
#1:  A                         5                       1.5
#2:  B                       NaN                       2.0
#3:  C                       NaN                      10.0
#    AV.DELAY_PERIOD_60 days_1
#1:                         1
#2:                       NaN
#3:                       NaN
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the aggregate function in R.

```
df1<-aggregate(df,by=list(df$id,df$period,df$type),FUN=mean)
```